# Joining 3 Tables (count like occurrences on post by user)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join the following 3 tables:

Table 1: posts
Structure: pid (post ID), message (content), poster_uid (user ID)

Table 2: users
Structure: uid (user ID), username

Table 3: likes
Structure: lid (like ID), pid (post ID), uid (user ID)

I want a counter of how many likes a post has, and so, I'd like to count like occurrences on a post (found by post ID) posted by a user (user ID).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result, so it is easy to understand your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You only want to count likes by post ID and user ID you don't need use JOIN for these tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM likes WHERE pid = :PID AND uid = :UID;
```

You retrieve same result with joins but this one is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Though your second requirement is not clear, hence For no of likes a post have you can try following:-

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(lid) AS COUNTER
FROM likes
GROUP BY pid;
```

And for second i think you want this:-

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(lid) AS COUNTER, uid
FROM likes
GROUP BY pid,uid;
```